# imshow shows different images for equal matrices?

Tags: octave

Let's say I want to invert the colours of an image and have written three functions to do so.

negativea.m:

```
function [negative] = negativea (image)
    negative = 255 - image;
end
```

negativeb.m

```
function [negative] = negativeb (image)
    [rows, columns, channels] = size(image);

    negative = zeros(rows, columns, channels);

    for i = 1:rows
        for j = 1:columns
            for c = 1:channels
                negative(i, j, c) = 255 - image(i, j, c);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

negativec.m

```
function [negative] = negativec (image)
    [rows, columns, channels] = size(image);

    negative = image;

    for i = 1:rows
        for j = 1:columns
            for c = 1:channels
                negative(i, j, c) = 255 - image(i, j, c);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Obviously a is the fastest on octave. The only difference between b and c is the initilisation of `negative`, but the values stored are never read in the function, only written. Unsuprisingly, all produced images are equal:

```
>> img = imread('logo.png');
>> nega = negativea(img);
>> negb = negativeb(img);
>> negc = negativec(img);
>> isequal(nega, negb) && isequal(negb, negc)
ans =  1
```

However, when drawing all images in a figure, the b image is not correctly drawn:

```
>> subplot(1,4,1); imshow(img);
>> subplot(1,4,2); imshow(nega);
>> subplot(1,4,3); imshow(negb);
>> subplot(1,4,4); imshow(negc);
```

Gives this result https://i.stack.imgur.com/8swAo.png The colours of b are not correctly inverted.

Now my questions is quite simple. Why?

P.S.: Using octave 4.0.1 on Windows 10 (x64)

P.P.S.: Perhaps the example of the octave logo was badly chosen, as it has an alpha channel. However the alpha channel seems to be dropped by `imread` as the number of channels is 3 and I have exactly the same issue with images without an alpha channel. This does not seem to cause the problem.

Comment: take a look at the function [`imcomplement`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/imcomplement.html) instead of writing your own (or at least takea look at it to see how to do it the most efficient way).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out the data type was to blame:

```
>> class(nega)
ans = uint8
>> class(negb)
ans = double
>> class(negc)
ans = uint8
```

The `zeros()` function returns an array of type `double` by default, while `imread()` returns `uint8`. The other image functions expect a data range from 0 ... 255 for integers but 0.0 ... 1.0 for floats. Therefor the inverted image produced by negativeb has most color values far beyond the sensible range. To fix this issue either initialise with the proper datatype in b:

```
negative = zeros(rows, columns, channels, 'uint8');
```

or convert the palette to range from 0.0 ... 1.0 in the loop:

```
negative(i, j, c) = double(255 - image(i, j, c)) / double(255);
```